# about bluetooth spp retransmission

Tags: bluetooth, acl, spp, l2cap

I am transmitting data from my development board to an Android Phone with Bluetooth SPP，and I am confusing about the SPP data retransmission.

According to the Bluetooth spec, packet is retransmitted if the sender receives a response packet with ARQN = 0. However, on my air packets log, I see a lot spp retransmission with out receiving any response, and I am curious about it.

I am afraid the retransmission decrease my throughput.

Does anyone know why the retransmission exist? thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe you will get retransmission when the packet is not acknowledged.  I am not familiar with the sniffer you are using, but generally you should observe a `NULL` packet in response to a packet received.  What does the spectrum look like?  Is the environment noisy?